# EC2 instance for loading databases

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

I'm doing experiments which involves loading a database from files into MySQL.

In my machine, 2.1Gh CoreDuo, the loading time takes less than 3 seconds.

I've tried to do it in an EC2 instance, with a medium, large and then High-CPU instance, but they all take an order of magnitude more (around 30 seconds).

Does anyone know what the problem here is? And is it possible to achieve the same performance as in my non-cloud machine?

Comment: Where are you loading the files from on the EC2 instances? How big are the files?

Comment: i uploaded the file to the instance and load it from there. Could it be possible that the file is stored somewhere else and not in the same machine as where the CPU is?

Comment: Well as far as I've always understood EC2, no, the storage of the VPS/instance itself is right there. Do the medium, large AND high-cpu instances all take the same amount of time? Then I would imagine it to be some kind of initialization thing. Weird, and something that needs to be looked into, but ...

Comment: i traced down the problem, it seems to be caused by JDBC (I loaded the database by reading through a well-formatted file and insert it to the database). On EC2, the time it takes for calling executeUpdate() is an order of magnitude slower. Does anyone know what's going on there?

Comment: Where is the database located? In the same instance where you are running your JVM? Is it possible that your local database has different tuning parameters (indexes, etc.) than the ones in AWS?

Comment: Are your settings between each environment identical? Do you have addtional logging turned on with your ec2 instance? Using EBS or instance storage?

Comment: i installed MySQL from scratch and used that, not touching any of the EC2 databases. The mysql server is running in the same instance where JVM is run

Comment: @datasage, how to check for logging or any other plugins?

Comment: You can run `show variables` command in mysql. Use that to compare your settings between your ec2 install and local install

Comment: ok, so the default storage-engine in EC2 is innodb, which is slower for insert than MyISAM. I switched back to MyISAM and now it's only 2 times slower (instead of order of magnitude like before). Thanks